# XQuery - Returning the whole document, not just selected/modified parts

Tags: xml, rest, xpath, xquery, basex

I'm trying to operate on some elements within an xml document without discarding the rest of the document. For instance, with the input

i.e. if I had

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <inventory><books>2</books></inventory>
  <bookList>
    <book category="COOKING">
      <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
      <stock>1</stock>
    </book>
    <book category="CHILDREN">
      <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
      <stock>0</stock>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
      <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
      <stock>1</stock>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
      <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
      <stock>0</stock>
    </book>
  </bookList>
</bookstore>
```

and wanted to just show the books in stock (i.e.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <inventory><books>2</books></inventory>
  <bookList>
    <book category="COOKING">
      <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
      <stock>1</stock>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
      <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
      <stock>1</stock>
    </book>
  </bookList>
</bookstore>
```

I know I could explicitly query the other pieces of the document and combine them together, but this is a significant amount of boilerplate, and fragile against document format changes. Is a better approach available?

**I should clarify that there may be unknown additional parts to the xml file above the bookList section that I want to preserve.** In other words, I don't want to have to say that I am making a new `<bookstore>` and include `<inventory>`. I would rather say that I want to include everything from my source document except for books with a `<stock>` value of 0. Also, if the `<bookstore>` element contained aditoinal information i.e. `<bookstore Name="David's Books" schema="www.bookLlist.org">` etc, that additional information should likewise be preserved.

Comment: Your examples are not well-formed XML. Please edit your question.

Comment: Thanks Ken and Mathias, sorry for the messy question, I have updated the question. You are right that the bad xml made my question more confusing and less useful. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: BTW, this question is still a lot bigger than it needs to be. If you don't mind, I might try to cut it down to the essentials to provide an example of how to build a good MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: You could try use a XSLT. It will permit generate other xml with specific filters/rules 
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_if.asp

Answer (score 1):

[XQUF (the XQuery Update Facility)](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update) makes this easy:

```
copy $c := doc('your-database')      (: select top of the document you want to return :)
modify delete node $c//book[stock=0] (: make changes you want :)
return $c                            (: return the whole document :)
```

The use of `copy` makes this a non-updating expression, so it won't modify your original datasource.

(XQUF [is a W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/); however, not all XQuery engines support it yet; BaseX is an early adopter).

Comment: @DavidK, I found a minor bug in my original answer -- `//book` needed to be `$c//book`; if you had trouble, try again.

Answer (score 1):

*Updated to support arbitrary elements.*

I think this use-case is perfect for vanilla XQuery:

```
xquery version "1.0";

let $doc := fn:doc($uri)/bookstore
return
  element bookstore {
    $doc/* except $doc/bookList,
    element bookList {
      $doc/bookList/* except
        $doc/bookList/book[xs:integer(stock) eq 0]
    }
  }
```

This will reconstruct the document, with every element except for `book` elements with a `stock` child element equal to `0`.

*removed now-irrelevant example ...*

Comment: Thankyou for this suggestion. If I understand you correction (and I acknowledge that I may not), this requires me to know what else is included in my document above the bookList. In other words, if I have another set of elements called CDlist, I would have to specify it in order for it to be included in the output. (see my bolded addition to the original question above).

Comment: I've updated the question with a completely generalized solution. Note: the XQuery 3.0 example doesn't meet these requirements, and no longer seems like a good fit.

Comment: Could you specify how my XQUF-based answer doesn't meet the requirements as given? (Perhaps as a comment on that answer, so its limitations are more visible to folks considering it).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that. I meant *my* XQuery 3.0 example (`local:projection()`, etc.) no longer meets the requirements. I had left it up for clarity, but it's adding confusion, so I've taken it down. I don't see any problems with your XQUF-based answer; I just prefer explicit transformation.